# Batch trim noisy images

Tags: imagemagick

I have a massive set of noisy images of drawings that people have created. I'd like to have some function to trim them down to ONLY the drawing.

Here are some examples:

[image: banana]
[image: cherry]

Because of the noise -trim doesn't work

I also tried to use the example linked here (www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#trim_blur), but it was ineffective because of differing noise levels both within and between images.

Lastly, I tried to increase the contrast to increase the likelihood of the lines of the actual drawing being identified, but for similar reasons to the above (differing noise levels), it only sharpened the lines in part of each image.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd love to hear them!

Comment: Usually a combination of blur & canny would be enough to isolate the region of interest in a noisy image. However both of your examples show valid markings at the extreme edges of the image (top-right of banana & bottom-right of cherry). Can we assume all markings at the edge(s) should be ignored?

Comment: Yes, that's a safe assumption that markings around the edge can be ignored, they are likely just random markings.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for all your images, as there are quite a few problems with them:

- artefacts around the edges
- uneven lighting, or shadows
- noise
- low-contrast

but you should get some ideas for addressing some of the issues.

---

To get rid of the artefacts around the edge, you could reduce the extent of the image by 2.5% on all sides - essentially a centred crop, like this:

```
convert noisy1.jpg -gravity center -extent 95x95% trimmed.png
```

[image]

---

To see the shadows/uneven lighting, I will normalise your image to a range of solid black to solid white and you will see the shadow at bottom left:

```
convert noisy1.jpg -normalize result.png
```

[image]

To remove this, I would clone your image and calculate the low frequency average over a larger area and then subtract that so that slowly changing things are removed:

```
convert noisy1.jpg \( +clone -statistic mean 25x25 \) -compose difference -composite -negate result.png
```

That gives this, and then you can try normalising it yourself to see that the shadow is gone:

[image]

---

If I now apply a Canny Edge Detection to that, I get this:

```
convert noisy1.jpg \( +clone -statistic mean 25x25 \) -compose difference -composite -normalize -negate -canny 0x1+10%+30%  result.png
```

[image]

---

Here is a very crude, but hopefully effective, little script to do the whole lot. It doesn't do any checking of parameters. Save as `$HOME/cropper`.

```
#!/bin/bash
src=$1
dst=cropped-$1
tmp="tmp-$$.mpc"
trimbox=$(convert "$1" -extent 95x95% -write "$tmp" \( +clone -statistic mean 25x25 \) -compose difference -composite -normalize -negate -canny 0x1+10%+30%  -format %@ info:)

convert "$tmp" -crop $trimbox "$dst"
rm tmp-$$.*
```

Make the script executable with:

```
chmod +x $HOME/cropper
```

And run with a single image like this:

```
cd /path/to/some/images
$HOME/cropper OneImage.jpg
```

If you have hundreds of images, **I would make a backup first**, and then do them all in parallel with **GNU Parallel**

```
parallel $HOME/cropper {} ::: *.jpg
```

Comment: this worked beautifully, thanks so much! After producing the image in your last step here, I was able to simply negate, then trim the output achieve the final result I wanted. Fantastic! Now I just need to string it all together.

Comment: I made a very simplistic little scripted version of the whole thing and added it in at the bottom. Good luck! Make a backup first please.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'm going to give this a shot later, but for now, just in case anyone else comes across this post and might find it useful, I used this command with pretty good results:

`for %i in (*.jpg) do magick convert “%i” –resize 10x10% -gravity center –extent 95x95% ( +clone -statistic mean 25x25 ) -compose difference -composite -normalize -negate -canny 0x1+10%+30%  -negate –trim “%i”`